# Ubuntu 14.04 broke docker network after few minutes

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

I create docker network on server with Ubuntu 14.04, run 2 containers in this network (hub and node) and try to ping hub from hode by container name. Its works for a few seconds or minutes, but after some time conection lost.

Network and containers:

```
docker network create grid
docker run -d --rm --net grid --name selenium-hub hub:v0.1
docker run -d --rm --net grid  -it node:v0.1 bash
```

Ping:

```
root@54385bbb4922:/# ping selenium-hub
PING selenium-hub (172.24.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.088 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.043 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=0.047 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=0.047 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=12 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=13 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=14 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=15 ttl=64 time=0.068 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=16 ttl=64 time=0.065 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=17 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=18 ttl=64 time=0.055 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=19 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=20 ttl=64 time=0.062 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=21 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=22 ttl=64 time=0.043 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=23 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
64 bytes from selenium-hub.grid (172.24.0.2): icmp_seq=24 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms
^C
--- selenium-hub ping statistics ---
54 packets transmitted, 24 received, 55% packet loss, time 52999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.040/0.052/0.088/0.012 ms
```

After conection lost docker still resolve container name to ip

```
root@2313d40e2018:/# ping selenium-hub
PING selenium-hub (172.17.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- selenium-hub ping statistics ---
2458 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2476656ms
```

This situation reproduse each time i remove and recreate network.

Meanwhile on my local system with Ubuntu 16.04 everything works fine.

I find this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/708487, but:
1) as far as i understand, there is no NetworkManager on the server

```
    ~$ ps ax | grep anager
  120 ?        S<     0:00 [charger_manager]
19798 pts/5    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto anager
```

2) adding `iface docker0 inet manual` to `/etc/network/interfaces` does not change anything

What else can automatically corrupt/reconfigure docker network?

Docker version 18.06.3-ce, build d7080c1

Comment: Are you sure that these containers are running ? have you checked `docker ps` ?

Comment: yes, i can make requests for web application im "hub" container and get correct responce. And i can see this requests in docker logs